# The servlets named [AdminValidate] and [com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminValidate] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception, servlet-mapping

When ever I try to execute certain files in my Project I get this error

"Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start"

The console shows following errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AdminValidate] and [com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminValidate] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2396)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2072)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2033)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Agro</display-name>
  <servlet>
   <display-name>AdminValidate</display-name>
   <servlet-name>AdminValidate</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AdminValidate</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/AdminValidate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I tried all the solution on stackoverflow but nothing seems to help...if there is any other solution to this problem please post here.

Comment: can you post web.xml code and server code

Comment: I know, it is caused by `The servlets named [AdminValidate] and [com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminValidate] which is not permitted`

Comment: This looks like the problem: `The servlets named [AdminValidate] and [com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminValidate] which is not permitted`.

Comment: exactly which solutions on stackoverflow have you tried? ^^

Comment: I have added the web.xml. There is one servlet in my project which is AdminValidate.java

Comment: The posted web.xml seems valid to me. Did you make any changes?

Comment: please post the full `web.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments have provided the answers, still i would like to post as an answer

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AdminValidate] and [com.kunal.servlet.AdminValidate] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminValidate] which is not permitted`

How would you expect the container to choose one servlet for an URL, when you have provided more than one servlet for the same URL pattern?

Please check the web.xml for more than one servlet mapped to the same URL pattern.

Think.

Comment: Thank you...error solved.....but now I an getting 

HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;

Comment: The method `javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()` is part of EL 2.2. so, you need to use a servlet container which supports it. Which tomcat version do you use?

Comment: It supports EL 2.2. Not sure why it happens, please check if you have any EL 2.1 jar version in classpath..

Comment: Thank you bro......both problem solved....I had added the wrong jar....